# Losing database update after changes in code

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sqlclient

I have a simple question. I'm new to .net and `sql` and I'm trying to write a small form application. I added a data source which I created in `sql`. I got `textboxes`, button to update tables in database.  When I made changes in database, like adding or deleting rows from tables, these updates are getting lost if I made a little change in application code (for example entering a new line).
Probably I'm unaware of something simple. What is the cause of it?

Comment: do you create your database dynamically in code?

Comment: Might be your changing in code is not updating the values in database.

Comment: No, i didn't create my database dynamically.

Comment: After a new row insert, program shows these updates, but if i close it, change some codes and run it again updates are getting lost.

Comment: Try to be more precises. Do the changes persist when running 2x without making changes?  What is your Db? Post the connection string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the database from solution explorer, go to properties (or alt + enter) and change the Copy to Output Directory to Copy if newer (copy if you change the database) or Do not copy. If the selected option is Copy always, the database is copied each time the project is build.